# When querying Firebase Realtime database, which of these is more efficient: query by key name, or query by its value

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

Below is the current structure of my database I'm using for a game, which contains 'rooms', and within each room, 'moves'. The move key is a randomly generated string, and I am storing the move number, 'n' as a property of that key.  I need to query the database to get the move data for a specific move number n:

```
{
  "rooms": {
    "-LXU8-36ISMY8YZnI7fr": {
      "moves": {
        "-LXZv-7zMCZdrH7ffoWf": {"n": 1, "x": 532, "y": 242},
        "-LXZv7LlQTkBEtls0PP2": {"n": 2, "x": 352, "y": 944}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I am achieving that like this - if for example I need move n=1, I am doing this:

```
moveRef = roomRef.child('moves').orderByChild("n").equalTo(1)
```

It is not clear to me from the documentation whether the filtering is done on the server, or whether all the moves would be downloaded to the client and then filtered, which would seem very inefficient.

Here is my question: Would it be more efficient (specifically, less data transferred to the client and thus cheaper) to instead set the key name for each move as the move number like this:

```
{
  "rooms": {
    "-LXU8-36ISMY8YZnI7fr": {
      "moves": {
        "1": {"x": 532, "y": 242},
        "2": {"x": 352, "y": 944}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then query by referencing the specific move I want, for example to get move 1:

```
moveRef = roomRef('/1');
```

It seems to me that this would be more efficient, but I am wary of using this method because I'm sure I read somewhere in the documentation that doing it this way was a bad idea.  Thanks.

Comment: As long as your query is [indexed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile#unindexed_queries), it's going to be OK.  You can use the [database profiler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile) to check the performance and find out if a query appears to scale poorly from being unindexed.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, I cannot index the query I want to make, because I don't know the key name of each move ahead of time. The key names are randomly generated, and they are added to the database dynamically by the client.  So I guess that means all the data under the 'moves' key is downloaded to the client each time I make a query.  That's why I want to know if my second proposed data structure would be better.  I'll check out the profiler though - thanks.

Comment: Ok so it seems my understanding on that was wrong - you don't need to know the name of the parent key in order to index it's child, as you can use the $ wildcard variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the moves with `n: 2` for a specific room, you can quite efficiently perform that query with:

```
moveRef = roomRef.child('moves').orderByChild("n").equalTo(1)
```

As long as you've defined an index on `n`, the query will be performed on the server. In your current structure that index would be:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "rooms": {
      "$roomid": {
        "moves": {
          ".indexOn": "n"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will scale quite well on the server, to at least a few hundred thousands moves (per room), and likely even to a million moves (again: per room).

But with your second data structure you can do a direct look up of the moves for a room with a specific `n` value. And a direct lookup is always going to be faster than a query, since you're telling the database exactly where to find the data.

```
roomRef.child('moves/1')
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense to me now, thank you.  I'll switch over to the second data structure to get the maximum speed.